# How to know my audio codec will support the output container in. Fluent-ffmpeg

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, video, codec

I am building a YouTube downloader. As YouTube doesn’t store high quality video with audio and store them separately so I have to merge them on server.

For merging I am using a Node.js server with fluent-ffmpeg and it is taking some time to merge.

BY doing some R&D I found that, I don't really need to encode the output video. If I just copy the audio file and video file to output file it's just way faster than before.

Now the problem is how can I know the output video file will support my audio codec or not?

My output video file has same extension as input video file but I am a bit confused about audio codec support.

Comment: Can you give an example link where the data are not simultaneously available? I just picked a random 4k video or two & they show many alternatives, WEBM or MKV with AAC or Opus attached, in resolutions from 2060p60 right down to 144p, or independent audio in M4A, AAC & Opus, also in a myriad qualities. This is in JDownloader, btw… just in case you might be trying to reinvent the wheel ;)